# Copy Paste Table from .docx into R as a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, clipboard

Is it possible to read/yank the clipboard contents of a .docx table directly into R as a data frame? Presently, I have tried to do this using clipr's `read_clip_tbl()` but the output ends up being all the contents (multiple variables) into a single variable column. The current manual workaround with this is I do this for each column in the .docx table and then bind them together.

Not sure if relevant, but:

- Running on Linux
- Xclip is installed
- Table being pasted from a .docx in Google Docs

Comment: did you ever try `read.table(textConnection('copy and paste your data here'))`

Comment: @SametSökel When I attempt this, each cell is pasted as a new line, and thus I can't run the function without first manually correcting the pasted output into a single line within the code.  I believe this is the same reason why any of the readClipboard functions that I've tried to use still output the dataframe as a single variable.

Comment: I think you could go with that, reshaping data in R environment would be easier. can you update your question with the broken shape of your data. we can check for making it into appropriate shape

Comment: Haye you tried {datapasta}? It does require RStudio IDE, though. https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta

Comment: I agree with @SametSökel, though if you highlight the table and then Copy (`Ctrl C`), then I can do `read.table("clipboard", header=TRUE)` and get my data; to R, it is really just tab-delimited text. Then again, I'm testing on a very simple 2x3 table with one line per cell. If you have embedded newlines (multi-line text in a cell), then none of this will work, since Microsoft clipboard ops butcher the format beyond easy repair.